# Adding another linux system to grub 2

Tags: fedora, grub2

As far as I can gather from the fedora website, I need to edit the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`  script to read:

```
menuentry "Arch Linux" {
        set root=(hd0,5)
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux
        initrd /PATH_TO_initramfs??
    }
```

How do I finish this, and what else do I need to modify such that I can boot into both OSes from my Fedora grub installation?

EDIT:
now that I got this working, I thing it is important to note that `grub2-mkconfig` must be run (or it may be named `grub-mkconfig`) in order for the changes to such scripts as the one mentioned above to take effect.

Comment: See the [Arch Wiki Grub2 entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB2#Dual-booting) for dual booting Linux OSes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the kernel image, initrd, and also (usually) kernel parameters so it will mount the arch root rather than your fedora root.

If your arch has an autogenerated grub.conf in its /boot/ you can probably just use (copy&paste) the menuentry from there, or make your fedora grub load the arch grub config. That way you wouldn't have to edit/update your fedora grub conf everytime arch installs a new kernel.

Something like this could work (but I haven't actually tested it):

```
menuentry "Switch to Arch Grub" {
    set root=(hd0,7) # your arch partition
    configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg # your arch grub.cfg
}
```